# what is Oracle command 'o;'

Tags: oracle, command, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlcl

I am using the oracle version.

```
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0
```

I accidentally ran the command `o;` in oracle delveloper.

The result is as below.

```
The PL/SQL procedure completed successfully.

not spooling currently
The sqlcl_int_runme alias has been removed.
```

I don't know what I did....

First of all, there seems to be no problem with basic table CRUD.

Has anyone had this experience?
I need an explanation of what happened...

Comment: I assume "oracle delveloper" means "SQL Developer", the database interface provided by Oracle. I will edit your tag to add SQL Developer; Jeff Smith, the product manager (yes, that Jeff Smith!), sometimes participates on this forum, and he may be the best person to answer your question. I will also add the `sqlcl` tag, since the question seems to have something to do with it too. (SQL Developer and SQLcl are maintained together, so this should not be surprising.)

Answer (score 4):

It's an alias.

We copied over some popular commands from postgresql to SQLcl, one of those was 'o'

From the post docs

> \o or \out [ filename ] \o or \out [ |command ] Arranges to save
> future query results to the file filename or pipe future results to
> the shell command command. If no argument is specified, the query
> output is reset to the standard output.
>
> If the argument begins with |, then the entire remainder of the line
> is taken to be the command to execute, and neither variable
> interpolation nor backquote expansion are performed in it. The rest of
> the line is simply passed literally to the shell.
>
> “Query results” includes all tables, command responses, and notices
> obtained from the database server, as well as output of various
> backslash commands that query the database (such as \d); but not error
> messages.

```
SQL> alias
\!          \?          \c          \cd         \d          \dp         \dt         \dt+        \e          \echo       \encoding   \i
\o          \p          \prompt     \q          \qecho      \r          \save       \timing     \w          \z          clear       cls
cpu         fuzzy       gglag       locks       sessions    tables      tables2     topsql
SQL> alias list \o
\o NULLDEFAULTS psql - desc \o [FILE_NAME] - turn spool log file on (or off if no FILE_NAME given)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Declare
  maxpos number:=null;
BEGIN
  if (:sqlcl_int_first is null) then
    :sqlcl_int_runme:='spool off';
  else
    :sqlcl_int_runme:='spool '||:sqlcl_int_first||' ';
  end if;
end;
/
alias NULLDEFAULTS sqlcl_int_runme=:sqlcl_int_runme;
sqlcl_int_runme
alias drop sqlcl_int_runme
```

To see it in action...

```
SQL> set sqlformat csv
SQL> o stackoverflow.csv

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Alias sqlcl_int_runme dropped
SQL> select * from regions;
"REGION_ID","REGION_NAME"
1,"Europe"
2,"Americas"
3,"Asia"
4,"Middle East and Africa"

SQL> o

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Alias sqlcl_int_runme dropped
SQL> !dir stackoverflow.csv
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is F897-6A6F

 Directory of c:\sqlcl\22.2.1\sqlcl\bin

08/30/2022  08:09 AM               170 stackoverflow.csv
               1 File(s)            170 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  190,156,173,312 bytes free

SQL> !type stackoverflow.csv
Alias sqlcl_int_runme dropped
"REGION_ID","REGION_NAME"
1,"Europe"
2,"Americas"
3,"Asia"
4,"Middle East and Africa"


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply!!!!!!
May I ask if I understand the example well?


Is it correct that all DB operations executed after changing sqlformat to csv format are output to a file called stackoverflow.csv?????
 Then 
```o;```  
After executing , all DB operations are output to the console, not to stackoverflow.csv! is it correct?

Comment: pretty much except you'll see output at both console AND the file, the file will be closed once you say you're done with the follow-up call to /o --- this is the equivalent of saying spool file and spool off